# How to handle js popup alerts inside WKWebview, like safari does ?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, uialertcontroller

I want to implement safari-like popup alerts, in my WKWebview, so they are not covering entire view.
I attached two screenshot of the same webpage, opened from safari, and from my WKWebView.
This is my code, to present js alerts:

```
func shouldShowJsAlert(message: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let alert =  UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        completionHandler()
    }))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Left is safari, Right is my WKWebView

[image: Safari][image: WKWebview]

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView requires you to show alerts, prompts, and confirms yourself. 
Do `WKUIDelegate.h`,

wkWebView.UIDelegate = self;

`- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler;`

Comment: Yes, I have this method, above code is called from the method that you mentioned.
However Safari show alert, not with typical UIAlertController, so I ask if someone have code for Safari style alert